# show window size in Firefox 57 (web developer)

Tags: firefox, web, window, size

I am using web Developer 2.0.1 in Firefox 57.
I can't find the old function to display the current window size inside the window or the browser-title.

It opens just shortly for information and disappers, if i resize the window.
How can i see the window size during resizing?